# Good Book on Permutations and puzzles

Tags: permutations, puzzle, book-recommendation

I need to study about permutations to mathematically analyze scrambling of digital images. Do you know any good books on this matter ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although the choice of books varies from person but The book I 'm reading is:

*Combinatorics -A Problem Oriented Approach*, 
an MAA book by Daniel A. Marcus.

It is written with a very good insight into the fundamentals of permutations and combinations.Also the book has lots of examples and exercises with every new topic introduced.

You can easily find it's djvu version online but make sure you have installed djvu reader in your PC...